# QTile custom widgets wont load

Tags: python, linux, archlinux, window-managers

I am trying to create a custom widget for QTile WM, but it wont work. I have python file named test_w.py in widgets sub-folder among all other widgets with following code:

```
import re
import subprocess

from libqtile.widget import base

class test_w(base.ThreadPoolText):
    defaults = [("update_interval",10,"Timer")]

    def __init__(self, **config):
        base.ThreadPoolText.__init__(self, **config)
        self.add_defaults(test_w.defaults)

    def get_number(self):
       output = 'aaa'
       return output
```

then I added "test_w":"test_w" line into **innit**.py file (commas are OK) and also added the widget into config file. However, i will get error.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whats wrong with your approach, but for me it works by simply putting the widget file in .config/qtile/ or in a  subdirectory of it and import it in my config.py.

For example:
I have a widget in a file called "network.py" inside a subdirectory of "~/.config/qtile/" called "extras".
So I need `import extras.network as net` in my config.py.